# Get All User Achievements From Steam API

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

Based on all of the documented endpoints i have seem the only way to get a list of user achievements is to get all the games and get the progress per game. This is fine, but from what I have seen so far a user can have 100s of games and sometimes 1000s. This means to perform a "quick" sync to get the total number of achievements the script ends up having to make a crazy amount of queries to the API. Its fine running through command line, but for 90% of the profiles i have tested with a real time sync will cause a browser timeout.

This method is highly inefficient for me and it cant be good on the steam API either. Is there any undocumented endpoint that will allow me to just get a list of the achievements unlocked with one query rather than having to do it the way i am doing it now?

Comment: Im searching for this now to, a very desperate task.

Comment: The give you some more Information, it is indeed not possible.
There is an API for that, Achievement Stat, but it always returns 0

Comment: Did you finally find something useful?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. There is no available endpoint for this. The solution i created looped over all games and got the lists separately. It was slow and never achieved what I wanted it to. It was very common for Steam players to have a huge number of games in their library